# How to read the fill pattern in Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010, office-interop

I am trying to import a spreadsheet that has a question on each row along with 4 possible answers. I can successfully read the cell values, but the correct answer is indicated by a fill pattern (50% Gray). I am using the code below to loop through the worksheet and pick out the correct answers.  However, the value of Pattern seems to be the same for all columns, even though the pattern is plainly visible on the worksheet.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

The worksheet is an .xls file. I am using Excel 2010 and VS 2010.

```
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim wks As Worksheet = wkb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim ur As Range = wks.UsedRange

    ' Load all cells into an array.
    Dim SheetData(,) As Object = ur.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)

    ' Loop through all cells.
    For j As Integer = 1 To SheetData.GetUpperBound(0)
        For k As Integer = 1 To (SheetData.GetUpperBound(1) - 1)

            'Get the pattern for the cells in columns 7 - 10
            If (k > 6) And (k < 11) Then
                Dim r As Range = wks.Cells(j, k)
                Dim s As Style = r.Style
                If s.Interior.Pattern = XlPattern.xlPatternGray50 Then

                    'Convert column index to "A" - "D"
                    Dim key As Char = ChrW(k + 58)

                    'Do something with key


                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I looked in MSDN but they give little or no explanation of how styles are stored in the object model. The few examples that I have seen show using the Style.Interior.Pattern to set the value after selecting the cell. Do I need to select the cell to read the pattern?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: all cells show -4142 (xlPatternNone) for the value of style.interior.pattern, even for cells that have a fill pattern of 50% Gray - which should be -4125 (xlPatternGray50).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Interior.Pattern` is accessible from a `Range` object. The `Range` interface/object contains all the style and value information for the range.

The `Style` property of the `Range` object refers to Styles that are definied at workbook level ("shared" styles).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.styles%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

> The Style object contains all style attributes (font, number format, alignment, and so on) as properties. There are several built-in styles, including Normal, Currency, and
>   Percent. Using the Style object is a fast and efficient way to change
>   several cell-formatting properties on multiple cells at the same time.

In your case (where the styles seems to be definied at cell level and not by using a "shared" style), you just need to replace:

```
 Dim r As Range = wks.Cells(j, k)
 Dim s As Style = r.Style
 If s.Interior.Pattern = XlPattern.xlPatternGray50 Then
```

With:

```
 Dim r As Range = wks.Cells(j, k)
'Dim s As Style = r.Style 'no need
 If r.Interior.Pattern = XlPattern.xlPatternGray50 Then
```

Comment: That was the missing piece to the puzzle.  It works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to vote yet, but I would if I could.  Thanks again Chris!